# How to delay an Azure Load Balancer Probe's first execution?

Tags: azure, load-balancing, azure-virtual-machine, azure-vm-scale-set

I have a custom azure load balancer probe which calls into our application code. The application is installed as part of creating the VM. It may take up to 10 minutes to install. In the mean time the probe is called by the load balancer, and if sufficient of the application is installed it corrupts the installation.

So, I would like to delay the first probe by 10 minutes. Is there a way to do this?

Note that I am using an ARM template to instantiate all the resources. So there may be a way to use dependsOn to have the probe be created after the last VM is available. Currently our dependency is load balancer (with Probe), then Scale Set then VMs. That order is forced as far as I can see.

So is there a 'warm up' setting somewhere?

Comment: Why cant you add two dependson conditions for the probe? load balancer and vm?

Comment: Could you please share the template?

Comment: The probe is part of the load balancer. The VM is part of the Scale Set. I can only see how to add a depends on at the Load Balancer and Scale Set level. The Load Balancer must be built first and then the Scale Set. The constituent parts of those objects, being Probe and vm, cannot be independently dependent. Or can they?

Comment: Here is the [template](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robe070/azure-quickstart-templates/feature/lansastack/lansa-vmss-windows-autoscale-sql-database/azuredeploy.json)

Answer (score 2):

There's no specific way to do this that I'm aware of. Some customers only add a probe after installation is complete to make deployment faster, and others set their application to not respond to the probe until the application is fully deployed. In both cases this will probably involve some design work on your application.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to schedule when probes start or stop.  You could prevent the probe from succeeding by defining and NSG and explicitly block AZURE_LOADBALANCER tag.  When the machine is ready, you could apply a different NSG that does allow the probe.  NSG's and tags for them are described here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-nsg/

You could expose a probe on a different port than the application itself and use that as a way to create a synthetic health signal.  This could be as simple as a valid path/file on an HTTP endpoint with an HTTP probe.  If the file is there, the probe succeeds.  Place the file there when your application is ready.

And there are probably several other ways for defining rules and probes and use them to achieve your goal by directing them not at the port that is delivering the service for the rule but to another port and away from your application.